# Python List Parsing

Tags: python

Probably a simple question, but I am new to Python. I have a file containing email addresses, one per line.  I want to read the file and append them together separated by a comma.  Is there a more pythonic way of doing this?

```
def getEmailList(file_name):
    f = open(file_name, 'r')
    emailstr = ''
    for line in f:
        emailstr += line.rstrip() + ','
    f.close()
    return emailstr
```

Answer (score 7):

You could do the following:

```
def getEmailList(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        return ",".join(x.rstrip() for x in f)
```

The key features of that version are:

- Using the [`with` statement](http://diveintopython3.org/files.html#with) so that the file is automatically closed when control leaves that block.
- Using the <del>[list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)</del> [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) `x.rstrip() for x in f` to strip each line *Thanks to [agf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/500584/agf) for that correction*
- Using [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to put a ',' between each item in the sequence

Answer (score 2):

```
','.join(line.rstrip() for line in f)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def getEmailList(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        result = ", ".join(addr.rstrip() for addr in f)
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def getEmaulList(file_name):
    with open(file_name, "r") as f:
        data = f.read()
        emails = ",".join(data.split("\n"))
        return emails
```

Keeps it simple.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
  emailstr = ','.join(line.rstrip() for line in f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `join` method to join together a set of strings.

```
def getEmailList(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        return ','.join([line.rstrip() for line in f])
```

Answer (score 0):

everything in one shot

```
",".join([x.replace('\n','') for x in open("yourFile.txt").readlines()])
```

Comment: I love the one-shot deals. but I am overwhelmed by the help here.  Thanks.  I know regex pretty well, but not in this context.  If an email address in the file was commented out with a '#", how could I filter those out?

Comment: With `",".join([x.replace('\n','') for x in open("yourFile.txt").readlines() if not x.startswith('#')])`

Comment: The problem here is that you don't close the file. You are depending on Python to close the file automatically when you've finished and some implementations will do that while others might take a while to get around to it and that could lead to annoying hard to find bugs. Always close files explicitly when you've finished with them.